# Geometric and algebraic intepretation of a probability function in quantum mechanics

Tags: real-analysis

A probability function in quantum mechanics is
$$P(x,t=0)=|Ψ(x,t=0)|^2=A^2e^{-p_0}\frac{\sin^2\left(\dfrac{Δpx}{2\bar h} \right)}{\dfrac x{2\bar h}}.$$
Plotting this function over an interval of $x$ gives

[image]

Geometrically, the plot shows that the function is finite and defined for $x = 0$. However, in the limit of $|\Psi(x, t = 0)|^2$ as $x$ tends to $0$, the function is $0$.

How do I reconcile this?

Edited:

Useful:

$\frac{sin^{2}\left ( x \right )}{x} = \left(\frac{sin\left ( x \right )}{x}\right)sin\left ( x \right )$

By the product rule of limit:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{sin^{2}\left ( x \right )}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{sin\left ( x \right )}{x}\right)sin\left ( x \right )$

where

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{sin\left ( x \right )}{x}\right) = 1 $

and

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}sin\left ( x \right ) = 0$

Comment: Why do you think the limit is 0? Also what does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: I've edited the title

Comment: @Rahul Check OP

Comment: Then the plot is incorrect. It looks like you have plotted something of the form $(\sin^2x)/x^2$ rather than $(\sin^2x)/x$. Alternatively, the plot is correct but the formula is wrong.